# Excel Sumproduct with Flexible Inequality

Tags: excel, sum, formula, sumifs, inequality

I'm trying to write a sumproduct that references other cells for its inequality conditions. I'd like to be able to change the direction of the inequality (i.e. <, >, <=, >=) by referencing a cell with that text instead of hardcoding the inequality in the formula. Is this possible?

This code works, where $B7 and $D7 are cutoff conditions:

> SUMPRODUCT(--('Data'!$A$2:$A$231>=$B7)*('Data'!$A$2:$A$231>=$D7))

However, variations of this code don't work, when I use references for the inequalities:

> SUMPRODUCT(--('Data'!$A$2:$A$231 & $B1 & $B7)*('Data'!$A$2:$A$231 & $D1 & $D7))

In the above case, $B1 and $D1 are both >=

Is it possible to do this with sumproducts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sumproduct() cannot integrate the comparison operator from another cell, but Sumifs and Countifs can.

```
=SUMIFS(A2:A50,A2:A50,B1&B7,A2:A50,D1&D7)
```

A2 to A50 has ascending whole numbers.

[image]

The condition does not make much sense, though, since both the Sumproduct AND the Countifs will use AND to combine the conditions. In this example both conditions use the same operator, so only the condition where the values are greater than D7 will be shown. It's a logic issue, not a formula one.

The formula only demonstrates how to combine comparison operators from a different cell into a Countifs (or Sumifs) formula.